# Why is my question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I am just wondering whether to say Calculus or Analysis.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209216/calculus-vs-analysis-when-applying-for-a-phd-involving-stochastics-what-do-i-s

Comment: Why downvote?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question resembles closely this excerpt from the help center:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where...your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

I suspect this is why your post got downvoted and closed.

Comment: Okay thanks I edited my question.